# Convert order by additional operator to sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I want to convert query MySQL into sequelize, but i don't know

```
SELECT * FROM `RewardEntries`
    ORDER BY `RewardEntries`.`happinessPoint` + `RewardEntries`.`moneyPoint` + `RewardEntries`.`healthyPoint` DESC
```

Please help me

thanks

Comment: Move the expression to the output list as additional column. Use this column name instead of expression in ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way to do this.  I've tested this with PostgreSQL, although the same would probably work for MySQL, too.

```
let rewards = await RewardEntry.findAll({                                                                                                                               
      order: [
        [ sequelize.literal('happinesspoint + moneypoint + healthypoint'), 'DESC' ]
      ]
    })
```

Here's a complete sample.  The name of the table in the database and all of its columns are all lowercase.  That's why the query has just lowercase in it.

```
let {
        Sequelize,
        DataTypes,
    } = require('sequelize')

async function run () {
    let sequelize = new Sequelize('mydb', 'username', 'password', {
            host:       'localhost',
            port:       5432,
            dialect:    'postgres',
            logging:    console.log
        })
    
    let RewardEntry = sequelize.define('RewardEntry', {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            HappinessPoint: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: 'happinesspoint'
            },
            MoneyPoint: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: 'moneypoint'
            },
            HealthyPoint: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: 'healthypoint'
            }
        },
        {
            tableName: 'rewardentries',
            timestamps: false
        })
    
    let rewards = await RewardEntry.findAll({
            order: [
                [ sequelize.literal('happinesspoint + moneypoint + healthypoint'), 'DESC' ]
            ]
        })

    console.log(JSON.stringify(rewards, null, 2))

    await sequelize.close()
}

run()
```